# Deserialize fragment of JSON using JavaScriptSerializer ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Is possible to `Deserialize` just a fragment of JSON using [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)? I don't need all data from JSON, just a section.

The JSON data look like this:

```
// **** snip ****
{
    "response":  {
        some data
    }
},
"forecast":  {
    "txt_forecast":  {
    "date": "7:00 AM PST",
    "forecastday":  [ // <-- section needed
        {
            some data....
        },
        .........
        {
            some data....
        }
    ]
},
"simpleforecast":  {
    "forecastday":  [
        more data
    ]
}
// **** snip ****
```

This is part I need to parse:

```
"forecastday":  [ // <-- section needed
    {
        some data....
    },
    .........
    {
        some data....
    }
]
```

I tried with `forecast` object ( fragment of whole data ), but it returns null.

```
var jsonData = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
forecast_class forecast = ser.Deserialize<forecast_class>(jsonData);
```

Comment: are you sure the JSON is valid if you need to validate that that JSON is valid use this link [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Because you don't want to build the *whole* object represented, you will most likely have to parse the string to get only the section you require. Once you have the section by itself, `Deserialize` it into an object. `JavaScriptSerializer` does not contain any methods to parse a specific section only.

Comment: @DJKRAZE JSON is valid, it's weatherunderground api.

Comment: @Jesse So I just need to cut part that I'm needed and `Deserialize` it?

Comment: Skomi, try the solution that I have provided If am correct this should give you the data where you have `forcast:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will something like this work for you

```
var dictObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonData);
var jsonNew = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dictObj["forcast"]);
```

Comment: It works. I just implemented this snippet three times for three "levels" (forecast -> txt_forecast -> forecastday). Will this slow my app?

Comment: This is something that you will have to test.. JSON is very light weight and should not add that much additional overhead in terms of slowing down it should speed it up actually in my opinion..glad I could provide you with a quick working solution..